# Modelsim for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, executable

I am looking to download modelsim for ubuntu. But the site gives only .exe file. Can I still install the software? Does modelsim exist for ubuntu? If yes, where can I find it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some more information in the future would be nice. It would for example be good to know what you exactly tried to download. If you look at the website again, you will see that ModelSim PE is only available for Windows. For a linux version you will need to download ModelSim DE.
http://model.com/content/modelsim-de-simulation-and-verification?quicktabs_1=1#quicktabs-1

Comment: ModelSim DE only has an evaluation model, right?